# How to share image through webview?

Tags: android, image, webview, share, onlongclicklistener

I need to share (possibility without download it) image from touch.facebook.com .

I actually use the handler:

```
  webViewFacebook.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // activate long clicks on links and image links according to settings
            if (true) {
                int type = webViewFacebook.getHitTestResult().getType();
                if (type == WebView.HitTestResult.SRC_ANCHOR_TYPE || type == WebView.HitTestResult.SRC_IMAGE_ANCHOR_TYPE) {
                    Message msg = linkHandler.obtainMessage();
                    webViewFacebook.requestFocusNodeHref(msg);
                    return true;
                }
                if (type == WebView.HitTestResult.IMAGE_TYPE || type == WebView.HitTestResult.SRC_IMAGE_ANCHOR_TYPE) {
                    String imageUrl = webViewFacebook.getHitTestResult().getExtra(); //  the image url

//here I have to share it directly

                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

but I get only the url.

How can I share for example [this](https://scontent-frt3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xft1/t31.0-8/fr/cp0/e15/q65/12697328_1862989287257822_3029644377886248821_o.jpg?efg=eyJpIjoidCJ9) image?
I would the function that Firefox for android has.

You can see all the code on [GITHUB](https://github.com/rignaneseleo/SlimSocial-for-Facebook/tree/master/SlimFacebook)